# Pendulum passing through a hole and acted upon by a force F

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

Let a pendulum pass through a small hole in the ceiling and acted upon by a force $F$. Let $r$ be the varying length of the string, $m$ the mass of the bob, and $\theta$ the angle from the vertical. Find the equations of motion.

[image: Pend]

The bob has two degrees of freedom since it's motion is not constrained by anything. From D'Alembert's principle,

> We vary $\theta$ and fix $r$, we get

$\frac{d}{dt} (mr^2\dot\theta) = -mgr\sin\theta$

> We vary $r$ by increasing an amount $\delta r$ and fix $\theta$, we get (according to Calkin's book$^1$)

The work gravity does is, $mg\cos\theta \delta r$

The work done by the inertial force is, $m(\ddot r - r\dot\theta^2) \delta r$

The work done by the force $F$ is, $-F\delta r$

This is where I'm confused, is this a mistake? The angle between $r$ and $F$ in Fig. 2.09 is not $180^{\circ}$, so how could it be that the work done by $F$ is $-F\delta r$? I think it should be $-F\cos\theta \delta r$, can anyone confirm this?

*1 Lagrangian and Hamiltonian Mechanics by Calkin

Comment: What was the original question? I have found it here https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uHtIDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=Fig.+2.09.+Plane+pendulum&source=bl&ots=oe8sU8IjSo&sig=A5hQHBhAOyi1roQYsBqwpwu-dK0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVxe7NpIbWAhVMBMAKHf6iA14Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Fig.%202.09.%20Plane%20pendulum&f=false

Comment: @Farcher I have edited my post, basically just find the equations of motion, but given that I have found the work done by each forces, then I could just use D'Alembert's principle and that is it. The problem is why the work done by the force $F$ is as given above.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your book might have been missing the dot product symbol for both lines two and three. You can replace this with $cos(\theta)$ and see if it gives you the right equation

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: i mean, work done by inertial force should also be multiplied by cos(theta), should it not?

Comment: Well that is what I wrote in my post. I think that Calkin wrote it incorrectly, but I need verification.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no friction between the string and the sides of the holes, only the normal force will act between them, so there is no difference in string tension before and after the corner at the edge of the hole.

Comment: Please so not answer textbook questions.  See comment below the original question.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero If you had looked at the book, this is not an exercise, but rather an example the author goes through. The OP's question relates to the fundamental physical understanding of the example.

Comment: apologies: my comment was a bit narrow.  Please do not answer *homework-like* questions.   You can read the  final consensus on this [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/36194) (this is the same link as above)… and I do have the book, which I highly recommend.